# How to capture url browsed?

Tags: c++, windows, http, networking, ftp

I wanted to know is there any hook, which can be added in Windows SDK for capturing url address if user starts browsing through internet(using any browser say IE, Firefox, chrome etc).

To be precise, i wanted to know is there provision to get HTTP/FTP access related callbacks from Windows Operating System (such as Win 2K, XP, Vista, 7 etc).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no easy/global way to do this (would be a bad idea regarding security I guess). I'd think the easiest way to do this would be writing a simple proxy server that just passes all requests/data. It's not like there's only one generic networking API that's used to process HTTP requests and such. Programs utilize Winsock to create sockets and then implement their own communication layer to send/retrieve messages and/or documents. You could try to hook those but you'd still have to process all packets sent/received to identify HTTP or FTP stuff ... don't think that's worth the effort.

If you'd just like to have some instance logging web requests, go with a prebuilt proxy (different web servers provide lightweight proxy implementations that don't require lots of configuration.

In the end it really depends on what you'd like to do.

Comment: Correct, there's no way to do this in general. If you want to build a proxy, you might consider starting with this: http://www.fiddler2.com/core